# Quiz Engine implementation

Tags: c#, api, quiz

I'm trying to find a nice API for a Quiz Engine. This is what I have so far:

**Implementation:**

```
public class Question
{
    public string Title { get;set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    public Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class QuizzEngine{
    Queue<Question> questions;

    public QuizzState QuizzState { get; set; }

    public QuizzEngine(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
    {
        this.questions = new Queue<Question>(questions);
        QuestionCount = this.questions.Count;
    }

    void StartQuizz()
    {
        QuizzState = QuizzState.Going;

        while(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going)
        {
            MoveToNextQuestion();
            if(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going) return;
            Answer answer = GetAnswer();
            TryAcceptAnswer(answer);
        }
    }

    Answer GetAnswer()
    {
        Answer answer;
        GetAnswerFromUI(out answer);
        return answer;
    }

    void GetAnswerFromUI(out Answer answer)
    {
        // somehow gets Answer through the UI
        answer = null;
    }

    public void TryAcceptAnswer(Answer answer)
    {
        var isCorrectAnswer = CurrentQuestion.CorrectAnswer.Equals(answer);
        if(isCorrectAnswer) CorrectAnswerCount++;
    }

    public void MoveToNextQuestion()
    {
        if(questions.Count == 0)
        {
            QuizzState = QuizzState.Finished;
            CurrentQuestion = null;
            return;
        }

        CurrentQuestion = questions.Dequeue();
    }

    public Question CurrentQuestion { get; private set; }
    public int CorrectAnswerCount { get; private set; }
    public int QuestionCount { get; private set; }
}

public enum QuizzState{
    Going,
    Finished
}
```

How could this be improved?

Comment: One tiny minor point: It's spelled "Quiz"

Comment: @NickUdell That's embarrassing, but let's ignore that for now.

Answer (score 8):

**Good**

- Meaningful names are used for classes, methods, parameter and properties
- using interfaces over implementation
- using enums to signal a state

**Not so good**

- **Code isn't tested**
- Scope of property setters is public where they should be private
- Using of properties which are never used
- Single responsibility principle is violated

The good things are said, so let us focus on the bad things.

**Code isn't tested**
How / where should one see this ?

> ```
> void StartQuizz()
> {
>     QuizzState = QuizzState.Going;
>
>     while(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going)
>     {
>         MoveToNextQuestion();
>         if(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going) return;
>         Answer answer = GetAnswer();
>         TryAcceptAnswer(answer);
>     }
> }
> ```

Here, after calling `MoveToNextQuestion()`, the code is checking the `QuizzState` property. So we assume the property has changed and if we take a look at this said method we see,

```
public void MoveToNextQuestion()
{
    if(questions.Count == 0)
    {
        QuizzState = QuizzState.Finished;
        CurrentQuestion = null;
        return;
    }

    CurrentQuestion = questions.Dequeue();
}
```

that the property is changed to `QuizzState.Finished`, if the question queue is empty. But the check is about `if(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going) return;`. So after the first call to `MoveToNextQuestion()` the code exists the while loop.

**Scope of property setters and never used properties**

As one of many samples let us take a look at the `Answer` class, so we can kill 2 birds with one stone

> ```
> public class Answer
> {
>     public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
>     public string Content { get; set; }
> }
> ```

The `IsCorrect` property is nowhere used in the whole code. But if it would be used somewhere, why should we allow to set / change the value of this property from a **public** place ? Especially for a Q&A engine, there shouldn't be a possibility to cheat !

**Single responsibility principle**

Where is the SRP viaolated ? Here

> ```
> void GetAnswerFromUI(out Answer answer)
> {
>     // somehow gets Answer through the UI
>     answer = null;
> }
> ```

The `QuizEngine` shouldn't be responsible for any UI related stuff. But wait, how are we supposed to receive the answers and also how should we notify another object ( like an UI ) about the next question ?

That is what events and methods or properties are for.
To signal a changed state, like there is a question to be answered, an event should be used by the `QuizEngine`.
To receive an answer for a question, the `QuizEngine` should provide either a property setter or a method.
For decoupling the `QuizEngine` and the `UI` the `QuizEngine` should implement an interface which provides the event and the answer setting method/property.

Comment: `The IsCorrect property is nowhere used in the whole code` I would probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then bind the IsCorrect property to a radio button. And i agree that GetAnswerFromUI was stupid. Forgot to make StartQuizz public.

Comment: `if(QuizzState == QuizzState.Going) return;` the if statement should check if QuizzState == QuizzState.Finished.

Answer (score 7):

A few points on top of [@Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher)'s excellent review.

---

Another violator of the single responsibility principle is the `MoveToNextQuestion` method, since it does two things:

1. Moves to the next question
2. Updates quiz state

When a method does something in addition to what its name suggests,
that becomes a burden on the programmer:
since the second action is not in the name,
you have to remember it,
or you have to re-read the implementation to be reminded.

When there is a single method like this,
it makes you question the entire class:
you cannot trust any of the methods, who knows what their implementations might be hiding?

This method should really have been simply this:

```
public void MoveToNextQuestion()
{
    CurrentQuestion = questions.Dequeue();
}
```

But then, when do you update the game state?
Technically, the very action of moving to the next question is in fact a change in the game state.
At least for now, it seems that looking at the state of the `questions` queue should be enough to check and manage the game state.
In particular, it will make sense to add a method for this:

```
public boolean HasNextQuestion()
{
    return questions.Count != 0;
}
```

With this, `StartQuizz` can be simpler:

```
public void StartQuizz()
{
    while (HasNextQuestion())
    {
        MoveToNextQuestion();
        Answer answer = GetAnswer();
        TryAcceptAnswer(answer);
    }
}
```

Notice that the original `StartQuizz` method was also violating SRP,
as it was messing with the game state too.
Now that's all gone:
this method doesn't need to know how the state is kept,
it just needs to know to run as long as there is a next question.

As a result, the `QuizzState` enum is no longer needed.

---

I fear the `QuestionCount` property can easily become a burden:

> ```
> public QuizzEngine(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
> {
>     this.questions = new Queue<Question>(questions);
>     QuestionCount = this.questions.Count;
> }
>
> public int QuestionCount { get; private set; }
> ```

What if you change something later in the behavior of the `questions` queue?
You will have to remember to adjust `QuestionCount` accordingly.
Instead of setting this property in the constructor,
it would be better to make this a method returning `questions.Count`.

---

Why think in terms of procedures?

> ```
> void GetAnswerFromUI(out Answer answer)
> {
>     // somehow gets Answer through the UI
>     answer = null;
> }
> ```

How about converting this procedure with a single output parameter to a function?

```
Answer GetAnswerFromUI()
{
    // somehow gets Answer through the UI
    answer = null;
    return answer;
}
```

This will also simplify the `GetAnswer` method:

```
Answer GetAnswer()
{
    return GetAnswerFromUI();
}
```